# Sync the building dependencies between local and jenkins CI server

Tags: c++, jenkins, build, cmake, artifactory

Assume I have a small team of ~10 C++ developers. I would like to setup an CI server with `Jenkins` to run the standard `build->test->release` flow. But usually the developers want to build and test their code before pushing to the git. So basically the code will be built both locally and remotely on the CI server.

How do I make sure that the dependencies used by each developers and the CI server is consistent?
I know that this may be related to what building tool I am using, but I am only familiar with `CMake`.

I've heard `JFrog Artifactory` might help by putting the dependencies on it, but could not find a good article on how to locally using that with `CMake`.

Am I heading to the right direction? Or there is a better way to setup this flow?

Comment: You should build using a docker image. So you can test locally or on any CI runners providing a docker daemon...
e.g. https://github.com/Mizux/cmake-cpp see the ci directory (I use make for orchestration build->test->install-> test install etc. BUT the project is CMake based...).

Then in your Jenkins (pipeline) setup simply call the makefile target you want...

Comment: @Mizux I am not very familiar with Docker, my understanding is that the docker image itself will have versioning concern, if the CI runner and the localhost use different image version, i still have potential consistency issue, right?